# investing in the development of

Tags: expressions

I find such sentence on the web, but is it correct?

> "people should invest in the development of their city"

If that's correct, can we "invest in the development" of some specific skills? (Such as intellectual skills: you would for instance donate to a school, or some of your time)

My sentence (concerning concerning social skills) would be

> "why not starting to invest in their development? "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily a *why* question of this sort takes a bare infinitive as complement of the interrogative:

> Why not start to invest in the development of social skills?

It is the very similar questions with *what about* or *how about* that take the gerund:

> What about starting to invest in the development of social skills?

By and large the gerund occurs with *why* only when this contrasts with a prior gerund—in effect, as a 'mention' rather than a use of the gerund.

> **A:** We're considering investing in the development of social skills.
>   **B:** Why 'considering'? Why not 'starting'?

Comment: thank you very much for your correction and your clear explanation!